# How to use Waterfall process in TFS

Tags: tfs, waterfall

I would like to manage a software project in Waterfall process style, which process template in TFS is suitable for?
Hasn't Microsoft supported waterfall in theire default process templates anymore?
For my project, I don't want to use Agile or Scrum process.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This describes the available processes/process templates: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process

Comment: There's nothing stopping you using those process templates for a Waterfall project. If those are not suitable for you, you can customise them.

Comment: "Anymore"? I've been using TFS for almost a decade and as far as I know there's never been an out-of-the-box Waterfall template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Process in TFS refers to an interdependent set of files used to create a team project.

There are three default processes in TFS: Agile, CMMI, and Scrum. They differ mainly in the work item types (WITs) they provide for planning and tracking work. Scrum is the most light-weight and CMMI, which stands for Capability Maturity Model Integration, provides the most support for formal processes and change management.

You may review the article below to get more information about TFS Process:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process